# How to group by per n days in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table like this:

```
//=> table name: my_table
+-----+---------+----------------------+
| id  | user_id |      created_at      |
+-----+---------+----------------------+
| 1  | 1        | 2021-04-06 12:35:36  |
| 2  | 1        | 2021-04-07 12:35:36  |
| 3  | 2        | 2021-04-07 12:35:36  |
| 4  | 2        | 2021-04-07 12:35:36  |
| 5  | 2        | 2021-04-07 12:35:36  |
| 6  | 2        | 2021-04-08 12:35:36  |
| 7  | 3        | 2021-04-08 12:35:36  |
| 8  | 4        | 2021-04-08 12:35:36  |
| 9  | 1        | 2021-04-08 12:35:36  |
| 10 | 4        | 2021-04-08 12:35:36  |
| 11 | 2        | 2021-04-08 12:35:36  |
| 12 | 3        | 2021-04-09 12:35:36  |
| 13 | 3        | 2021-04-09 12:35:36  |
+-----+---------+----------------------+
```

I need to group the table above based on `user_id` and `each_two_days`. So the expected result is:

```
//=> period: 2 days
+-----------+---------+-------------------+
| count(1)  | user_id |  min_date         |
+-----------+---------+-------------------+ 
| 2         | 1       | 2021-04-06        | -- for dates: 2021-04-06 and 2021-04-07
| 1         | 1       | 2021-04-08        | -- for dates: 2021-04-08 and 2021-04-09
| 3         | 2       | 2021-04-06        |
| 2         | 2       | 2021-04-08        |
| 3         | 3       | 2021-04-08        |
| 2         | 4       | 2021-04-08        |
+-----------+---------+-------------------+
```

Any idea how can I do that?

---

Generally, I want a query like this:

```
select count(1),
       user_id,
       min(date(created_at)) min_date
from my_table
group by user_id, <each 2 days based on "created_at">
order by user_id
```

Comment: `GROUP BY DATE(created_at) DIV 2`. Of course, 31th (and Feb, 29th) will form single-day group. For continuous range use `GROUP BY DATEDIFF(created_at, some_base_date) DIV 2`.

Comment: @Akina Great .. thank you. Just what's "some_base_date" ?

Comment: *Just what's "some_base_date" ?* Some constant date literal / value. For example, it can be `'2021-01-01'`, or minimal date in your dataset. First option guarantees groups independence when yuou apply different WHERE to your dataset, second guarantees that the least date won't form one-day group.

Comment: @Akina Ah. to be sure about the second option, assuming I have a where clause in the query like this: `where date(created_at) >= '2021-04-07'`, then what should be the second option?

Comment: With this WHERE `MIN(created_at)` will return `'2021-04-07'`, it's obvious... so this constant may be used as a base.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions.  One method calculates the number of days since the earliest day and then divides the difference by two:

```
select min_date + interval 2 * floor(datediff(created_at, min_date) / 2) day,
       user_id, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             min(date(created_at)) over () as min_date
      from my_table t
     ) t
group by user_id, min_date + interval 2 * floor(datediff(created_at, min_date) / 2) day
order by user_id, min(created_at)
```

The real complication is getting the first date in the range, for the users who only have rows on the second of the two dates.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=077a8aa40ddf7b8db5b8a1062781cdd4) is a db<>fiddle.